# Java: infinite loop after an if inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, infinite

So I have a loop that is wrapped around a loop and an if statement. When running the program however, it gets out of the inner loop (as planned) and then it fails the if statement (also as planned), resorting to the else statement which is a simple print.

What I /wanted/ to happen was have it then (in the case the if fails), restart to the original inner loop--hence the outer loop. But instead, after it fails the if statement, it begins to loop "phrase2" over and over.

Here is the simplified code:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int i = 0;
while(i == 0)
{
    while(<condition that is false>)
    {
        System.out.println("phrase1");
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();        
    }
    if(<condition that is false>)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("phrase2");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help regardless!

EDIT:
For the sake of emphasis...
What happens:
Infinite loop spewing "phrase2".
What I wanted:
After the else is executed, I wanted to be brought into the inner loop again.

Comment: It looks like once you hit the "phrase2" case, you never update any other data, and so of course the conditions that used to be false remain so. You may want to perform some kind of re-initialization in the `else` statement so that you restart properly.

Comment: If you are correct that `<condition that is false>` is indeed always false, then `i` never changes from zero, so of course the `while(i == 0)` will infinitely run. `i` needs to change somehow.

Comment: It may be that the conditions themselves are the problem; can you please add them?

Comment: in your else clause make <condition that is false> true

Comment: Looks like you are having a spaghetti attack; have you considered ways you can restructure your code to avoid the issue altogether?

Comment: @aliteralmind The conditions depend on a and b which are given the opportunity to change within the inner loop.

I should also add that the conditions are really long and rather messily made.

Comment: And could you make it clearer which parts of your description are what you _expected_ to happen, and which parts are what is _actually_ happening.

Comment: Hi, you need to somehow set the condition for the if statement to true in order for it to enter that if statement. Same goes for the inner loop.

Comment: We need a lot more context in order to help you. We are all basically saying that there needs to be a loop terminator, but since your code is so abstract, we can't know how to implement it.

Comment: @AlvinBunk would setting a and b so they are incorrect for the inner loop get that loop to start again?

Comment: While your attempt at a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is appreciated, please read that page and fix your example.

Comment: Hi @anakhronizein. Essentially you code looks ok. The only reason it keeps looping `phrase2` over and over again is because you aren't (I presume this) changing the condition `<condition that is false>` for the first while loop. Once you do that, the first while loop will be entered, but unfortunately the if that follows the while after it will then run and then exit the outer loop. Is that what you wanted to do? It seems to me that you may have wanted the if statement have a different condition to check (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever condition you're using in the inner loop, just make sure it's true.

```
else
{
    System.out.println("phrase2");
    // SET THIS TO TRUE: <condition that is false>
}
```

This way, the inner loop will trigger again.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue.
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your control never enters the below if statement

```
if(<condition that is false>)
{
    i = 1;
}
```

You might need to adjust your conditions so that it comes into the above if block. Introduce a System.out.println inside if statement to debug

Comment: That's not really what he's asking about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some code that you probably want to run once, unless something went wrong, and then you want to go back and retry.  The idiom I usually use for that looks like

```
boolean needToRetry;
do {
    needToRetry = false;
    // do whatever
    if (somethingWentWrong) {
        needToRetry = true;
        // set this at any point where you find you will need to go back
    }
} while (needToRetry);
```

The important thing is that you need to reset your flag (`needToRetry`) at the beginning of the loop, each time.  (P.S. There are other ways to do this using `break` or `continue`, although I personally don't like using `continue`.)